# Installed Android Studio successfully. I didn't get any shortcut to launch the Android Studio

Tags: software-installation, android-studio

At the end of installation Android Studio, I had been launched but after closing that application I didn't find any way to open it again. I have tried to create a shortcut but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The Easiest way is,
Run android studio from terminal then click on Tools-Create Desktop Entry. Now you will get Android Studio icon to launch it directly.
To show this icon in left dock search Android studio and drag and drop